# port 80 is free but apache can not connect

Tags: apache

I am trying to install Apache 2.4, I have downloaded the 2.4 zip and unzipped it, no I want to install it I ran the command.

```
C:\Apache24\bin>httpd
```

and I get the error code.

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::f5ef:aeb7:3922:e603. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I then ran the command

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -o -n -a | findstr :80

TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
TCP    192.168.1.100:50103    104.82.216.43:80       TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.1.100:50113    185.31.18.134:80       TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.1.100:50114    185.31.18.134:80       TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.1.100:50119    72.21.202.25:80        TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.1.100:50127    104.156.81.134:80      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.1.100:50131    185.31.19.130:80       ESTABLISHED     9564
TCP    192.168.1.100:50171    54.225.116.195:80      TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.1.100:50176    54.246.122.38:80       ESTABLISHED     9564
TCP    192.168.1.100:50190    23.23.141.250:80       TIME_WAIT       0
TCP    192.168.1.100:50191    155.133.248.14:80      SYN_SENT        7212
TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
```

and From this I think port 80 is free but am still not able to run Apache can any one help?

Comment: The top line doesn't mean port 80 is free. It means something is listening on port 80 on all interfaces. The culprit is probably the WinHTTP service - you can try stopping that in control panel.

Comment: ahh thanks, how do I free it

Answer (score 1):

The port is not free its blocked, run

> net stop was /y

to free the port